# Devise older version compatibility in new Devise git repo version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am working on a project where the live site is now using

Devise 1.0.6 with Rails 2.3.8.
There, its not using pepper (as this is switched off by default in 1.0.6 with sha1 as default I guess..(don't know what is default alg. in 1.0.6))

In my latest code, I have updated the devise version from its git repo, so my current snapshot of code uses

Devise 1.2.rc with Rails 3.0.1
Here in my current code, devise uses a default pepper value written in my devise.rb and it uses sha512 as its encryption algorithm I guess (don't know what is default alg. in 1.2.rc).

In both the old code and new code, in devise.rb, a custom alogirthm for encryption is not set. So devise uses its default encryption algorithms in live site( devise 1.0.6) and in my current latest code ( 1.2.rc)

1. I don't know which is the default encryption algorithm in Devise 1.0.6 and Devise 1.2.4c. Can you please tell me how to check this default algorithm.
2. Live site uses no pepper and my current code uses a default pepper given by Devise. which means that my old users will not be able to login if I start using the new default pepper give in 1.2.rc. How do I handle this. Shall I turn off the pepper option in my new code ? Please advise.

I could use the same devise version 1.0.6 but a lot of functionalities like open auth are available in the new devise version - so I am using the new one. Please advise on what to do.

thanks